# Import a Python Dictionary into a Matlab struct

Tags: python, dictionary, jsondecoder

I'm missing something very fundamental in the process of passing a trivial Python dictionary into a Matlab program.  The example I'm showing is reduced to the bare bones; my desired objective is much larger than this, but if I can't get this to work I have no hope on the larger one.  Here's the Python Code in file demo.py in the same directory as the Matlab console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

def get_demo_map():
    dd = {}
    dd['abc'] = 1
    dd['def'] = 'XYZ'
    dd['mat'] = [[1,2], [3, 4]]
    return json.dumps(dd).__str__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_demo_map())
```

With that in place, this Matlab (R2021a) console history tells the whole story.  I read the JSON string, but jsondecode() rejects it.  Then I make an identical Matlab string and jsondecode() does what I expect.  So clearly I'm missing something, and it looks like I need to convert the "Python str with no properties" into a proper Matlab string.  But how?  Or is it something else entirely?

```
>> dd=py.demo.get_demo_map()

dd = 

  Python str with no properties.

    {"abc": 1, "def": "XYZ", "mat": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}

>> ddmap = jsondecode(dd)
Error using jsondecode
JSON text must be a character vector or a scalar non-missing string.
 
>> ddstr = '{"abc": 1, "def": "XYZ", "mat": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}'

ddstr =

    '{"abc": 1, "def": "XYZ", "mat": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}'

>> ddmap = jsondecode(ddstr)

ddmap = 

  struct with fields:

    abc: 1
    def: 'XYZ'
    mat: [2×2 double]

>>
```

Comment: As an aside, `return json.dumps(dd).__str__()` -> `json.dumps(dd)`. `json.dumps` **always returns a string**. And if it didn't, you should never call the dunder method directly, i.e. `return some_object.__str__()` should be `return str(some_object)` but in this case, `some_object` is *already a string*

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it first without the __str__(), got the error, so my first attempt was to make sure I was getting a string.  I've taken it out now because I hate cruft.

Comment: A workaround, for the moment at least, seems to be to skip the JSON conversion and just return the Python map (dd, in this case) directly, but then, since it's a Python object, it must be addressed like dd{'abc'} instead of the normal Matlab dd('abc').  I can live with that for the moment.